# Find path between nodes through cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created a application the fills a Neo4J database with emails records. I created 2 types of nodes, person & mail and I created 4 types of relationships, sent, cc, to & reply_of.

Now I want to find relationships between 2 nodes that aren't directly connected. For example between P1 & P3 (see picture).

How can I achieve this through cypher? Is it doable in neo4j?

[image: Relationship between persons & mails]

Updated question:

First let me clear something about the picture...

The Reply_OF relationship is a relationship between mail nodes. It creates a relationship between the original mail and any reply of forward mail. The Sent, To, Cc & Bcc relationships create relations between a person node and a mail node. There is no direct relation between person nodes.

Submitting this question and reading the answers made me realise I wanted to know something else...what I really would like to know is how can I show all person nodes that have seen a reply or forward mail from the original mail that where not on the To, Cc or Bcc lists in the original mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to the updated question:

I assume your email nodes carry a label of `Email` and have a property `mailId`.

```
MATCH (mailToTrack:Email {mailId: 'mymailid'})-[:Reply_Of*1..100]->()-[:TO|:CC|:BCC]->(person)
RETURN distinct person
```

Comment: I get `Unknown variable 'UNNAMED35'.` on  `MATCH a=(first:IfcNode {nid: 587})-[:RELTYPE*1..2]->()-[:RELTYPE]->(other) RETURN distinct other;`. If  I remove `*1..100`, it works, but only does one hop, of course. On Neo4j 3.2.0

Answer (score 6):

In Neo4j terms you want to find paths between P1 and P3. A relationship connects just two neighbors.

I assume `P` nodes carry a `Person` label, and have a `name` property, in which case you can use:

```
MATCH p=(p1:Person {name:'P1'})-[:SENT|:TO|:CC|:BCC*1..20]->(p3:Person {name:'P3'})
RETURN p
```

In a lot of cases you're interested in the shortest path between them:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((p1:Person {name:'P1'})-[:SENT|:TO|:CC|:BCC*1..20]->(p3:Person {name:'P3'})
RETURN p
```

Comment: The relationship should be directionless, but otherwise, yes, this will work.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for your answer. It is not the shortest path I am after, I want to find all communication between two or more nodes.

Comment: @Josh what do you mean by directionless in this case?

Comment: The Cypher query in the answer shows relationships with -[]-> arrows on them, but your graph shows connections between people in both directions (like the Reply_Of type). Drop the ">" character from the query on order to get those paths as well.

Comment: depends on the semantics of your query: if you want all communication between P1 and P3, you're right. If you want communication flowing from P1 to P3 you need directed relationships.

Comment: Thx Josh and Stefan for your answers. They made me realise I wanted to know something else..pls see my update question. Tnx in advanced!

Comment: what does the `1..20` in the query mean? Is there a way to order by some value on the edge property - eg number of mails sent by that pair?